# Jump browser window down to a DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

OK, I'm sure I'm justing having a brain-fart after 2 weeks Honeymoon in Tuscany... by brains clear, and I'm googled out looking for keywords and how to do it, even scanned down the JQuery Valdate.js looking for the bit that does it...

What I want to do is this; but don't know where to start.

if ($("#errorMessage").exists()){

// Jump browser window down to #errorMessage.

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate it down, like this:

```
if ($("#errorMessage").length){
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#errorMessage").position().top });
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/LGLBg/), this just gives a nice transition to the element's positon.

Answer (score 0):

[scrollIntoView](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Methods/scrollIntoView.htm) would probably solve your problems.

And `.exists()` would be `.length > 0`

Comment: Yeh, got a besoke JQuery function that does exactly that, so I can just do an exists() - jQuery.fn.exists = function() { return jQuery(this).length > 0; }

Comment: @Will - When writing a plugin just use `this.length`, `this` is already a jQuery object inside that context :)

Answer (score 0):

check [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) property. you will have to scroll to the [position](http://api.jquery.com/position) of the element